# app store approval for location-based app if server has data for only one city

Tags: geolocation, appstore-approval

I've built an app which depends heavily on downloading data from a server.  This data only has value within a specific area.  The server will only have data for one city to start with (and it's not Cupertino), so unless the app approver person is physically in that city, they'll get no data. (The app still works in this case, but it's terribly uninteresting).  Is that grounds for rejection?  If not, how would Apple know if the app works or not?
TIA,
-Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, now that you've all had a chance to comment, this is what I did to solve this little dilemma.
I added a "Drop Pin" feature to allow the user to pretend to go anywhere on the map that they wanted to.  Then I just used that lat/lon from the UIMapView to query for data.

Edit:

Here is where you can explain these circumstances to the app review team:

From ["App Store Submission Tips - Providing Additional Info for the App Review Process
"](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/submission/tips.html)

> If your application requires specific settings, user registrations or account information prior to submission to the App Store, be sure to include that info in the field "Demo Account - Full Access" on iTunes Connect. This is a text field visible only to the App Review team, so the information entered in that field will not be viewable on iTunes to the general public. You can also include general instructions or other relevant information about your application which you think would be useful for the review process.